# make command not working ERROR 2

Tags: drivers, compiling, make

I was trying to install `Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07` which I downloaded from [here][1]

When I run the make command I get the following error:-

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

I have 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed.

Comment: Your link is not working, can you please add the correct one?

Comment: here is the link ftp://WebUser:AxPL9s3k@95.130.192.218/pc/crc/Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07.zip

Answer (score 0):

I believe the file is too old to compile on Ubuntu 14.04. It won't compile on my system either. I notice that there are a number of files in your package named rtsx.something. There are several drivers called rtsx built in:

```
/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/memstick/host/rtsx_pci_ms.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/mfd/rtsx_pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.ko
```

Are you certain that the driver you need isn't already present? What does this tell us about the device?

```
lspci -nn
```

I suggest you try:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/mcfloundinho/rts5229.git
cd rts5229
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe rts5229
```

It makes with one warning but no errors on my system.

Please edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf to change this line:

```
#Wireless drivers conflicting with rt3562sta
```

To this, with a space:

```
# Wireless drivers conflicting with rt3562sta
```

Proofread, save and close the text editor.

You have compiled the driver for your currently running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a newer linux-image, after the requested reboot, re-compile:

```
cd rts5229
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe rts5229
```

Comment: I have ubuntu 12.04 not 14.04

Comment: I have ubuntu 12.04 not 14.04 and lspci -nn shows  a big list of all Host bridge and in the last I found this 01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
03:00.1 Bluetooth [0d11]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth [1814:3298]

Comment: Although you have 12.04, your kernel, 3.13.0-xx, is the newer kernel used in 14.04. Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Till sudo make install everything goes fine but sudo modprobe rts5229 gives error

WARNING: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf line 56: ignoring bad line starting with '“blacklist'
FATAL: Module rts5229 not found.

Comment: Please see my edit above. Notice the addition of sudo depmod -a

Comment: same error persists

Comment: The module rts5229 error or the blacklist warning? Are you sure you started with 'make clean'?

Comment: yes I am definately sure i started with make clean and Its blaclist error at line 56

Comment: The blacklist is a warning, not an error. Let's see the file: cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf Paste the result here and give me the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com Did the module load? lsmod | grep rts

Comment: here is the link http://paste.ubuntu.com/7836775/

Comment: Your new module loaded just fine! Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: After you read my edit, if my answer has been helpful, please accept it.

Comment: I want to another driver of bluetooth plzz help me with this I downloaded the file from http://s3.amazonaws.com/mtk.cfs/Downloads/linux/-2012_0508_RT3290_Linux_STA_v2.6.0.0.bz2

it also shows the same error

Comment: I think that is for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Install the drivers from Ubuntu Main Repository:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

then reboot.

Comment: it didn't worked